# Published Azure Function doesnt trigger on Service bus message

Tags: c#, .net, yaml, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I`m having trouble with published (from VS code) Azure Function which is suppose to trigger when a message was added to the queue, unfortunately once message is added nothing is happening, function execution count is always 0, logs are empty. Everything is working locally and I really have no clue how could I make this work.

Configuration variables are populated, containing:

[image]

This is my yaml file:

```
- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: AzureAppServiceSettings@1
  displayName: Update App Service Settings
  inputs:
    ConnectedServiceName: $(ServiceConnection)
    resourceGroupName: $(ResourceGroup)
    appName: $(WebApp)
    slotName: 'production'
    appSettings: |
      [
        {
          "name": "Values:test",
          "value": "$(test)",
          "slotSetting": false
        }
     ]
- task: AzureAppServiceSettings@1
  displayName: Update Azure Function Settings
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: $(ServiceConnection)
    resourceGroupName: $(ResourceGroup)
    appName: $(FunctionApp)
    slotName: 'production'
    appSettings: |
      [
        {
          "name": "test2",
          "value": "$(test2)",
          "slotSetting": false
        }
      ]
- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  inputs:
    ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
    azureSubscription: $(ServiceConnection)
    appType: 'webApp'
    WebAppName: $(WebApp)
    deployToSlotOrASE: true
    ResourceGroupName: $(ResourceGroup)
    SlotName: 'production'
    packageForLinux: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.zip'

- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  displayName: Deploy to FunctionApp
  inputs:
    ConnectionType: "AzureRM"
    azureSubscription: $(ServiceConnection)
    appType: 'functionApp'
    WebAppName: $(FunctionApp)
    deployToSlotOrASE: true
    ResourceGroupName: $(ResourceGroup)
    SlotName: 'production'
    packageForLinux: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.zip'
```

Function code:

```
        [FunctionName(TopicBeginFunction)]
        public async Task ConsumeStatusMessageFromQueue(
           [ServiceBusTrigger("%TopicBegin%", "%SubscriptionBegin%", Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString")]
        Message topicMessage, CancellationToken cancellationToken, ILogger logger)
        {
            logger.LogInformation("Started");
            try
            {
```

Thank you in advance for help!

Comment: Please don't post code using a picture, it is impossible to read it easy.

Comment: 1. Do you see your function deployed in the portal? 2. Do you get any invocation errors? 3. Are messages consumed from the subscription or not? Eliminate the most obvious ones to deduct what's going on.

Comment: So when I set WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE to 0 I can see my two functions otherwise I got message: "Your app is currently in read only mode because you are running from a package file". 
2. All errors that I got I fixed and now there arent any.
3. Messages are not consumed - service bus have actives messages and nothing is happening with them.

Maybe its the fact how I build my solution? $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.zip
contains both app service and function project

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for the valuable suggestion @*Krzysztof*,
for resolving the above issue as you have confirmed the ***workaround*** posting as an answer to help other community members for the similar queries.

- ***After adding `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE` to `0` instead of using `1` has resolved the issue.***

*Please refer the below links for the similar issues:-*

- **MS Q&A:-** [***azure function not able to receive message from servicebus***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/531648/azure-function-not-able-to-recieve-message-from-se.html)
- **SO THREAD:-** [***Azure Function (Service Bus Trigger) Not Getting started when a new message comes into the service bus queue.***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71668612/azure-function-service-bus-trigger-not-getting-started-when-a-new-message-come)